# Endless loop variables: does make an array inside endless loop wasting memory?

Tags: go

Is this go code wasting memory by declaring the same array variable in an endless loop?

```
for {
    rxArr := make([]byte, 4500)
    ...
}
```

Comment: See https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2018/12/garbage-collection-in-go-part1-semantics.html (overview and "quirk" for 1.12), GC loop non-preempting seems to be addressed in 1.15

Comment: @user2864740: In other words, the big question is whether this code wastes time garbage collecting.

Comment: @luther If it should garbage collect, it doesn't waste any time doing so (as collecting garbage is never wasted time, regardless of maybe-too-many creations).. the object is always created and it is (presumably) _not_ strongly reachable upon re-assignment of the the variable. However, if the "endless loop" cannot be pre-empted for GC (version specific) then there might be an issue. To analyze wasting memory, or if there is a strong reference preventing GC, would involve knowing what "rxArr" is for as well as the remainder of the code. Anyway, links above..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every loop will create a 4500 byte array. If any references survive to that array from iteration to iteration or outside the for-loop, then that array will not be garbage collected. If no references survive, it will be garbage collected.

In your example, you're redeclaring the `rxArr` for each iteration, and none of those survive from one iteration to the other. So, all will be collected.